# Published app has no custom images when installed from store

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-mobile, uwp

My app is published in Windows Store now, but when I install it from the store, all of my custom images are missing. When I install via debugger from VisualStudio everything is fine. Is there maybe a missing resource note in appxmanifest for using custom images, by any chance?

Example:

```
<Button x:Name="myBtn" Grid.Row="0" Tapped="myBtn_Tapped" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleMenu}" BorderThickness="0" ClickMode="Press">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="alert" Stretch="Fill" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/my/menu/btn.scale-100.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="25" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="btnTxt" Text="ClickMe" FontSize="18" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "custom images"? Are we talking about app icons and tiles or resources within the app?

Comment: It means .png images I used for menubuttons etc. All assets that I declared in appxmanifest assistant work fine. Other resources are bound with path like this <Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/my/myicon.scale-100.png" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Width="41" Height="53" >

Answer (score 2):

You should not be looking for a qualified asset, like btn.scale-100.png. Instead, you should look for an unqualified asset like btn.png, and Windows will automatically load the right resource depending on the scale-factor of the OS.

This article does explain the concept at some depth: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/08/08/developing-world-ready-apps-in-xaml-part-2/